# Push and Pull Bootstrap Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

**Desired Grid xs screen to sm**

[image]

I'm trying to reorder my grid in other to put a nested grid next to the blue section. This is the code I have right now, but the push and pull causes the orange squares to disappear.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="test-slider col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">Slider</div>
  <div class="test-quickhelp col-sm-12 col-sm-push-6">QuickHelp</div>
  <div class="test-square-top col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">s1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">s1</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the push and pull"?

Comment: @Niek he means Column Ordering -> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the `push` and `pull` classes alone.

These classes only add relative `left` and `right` CSS properties to the element, so you cannot move elements up and down.

I believe you will have to duplicate the content and hide\show it based on view-port.

Something like this...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="test-slider col-sm-6">Slider</div>
  <div class="test-square-top col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test-quickhelp col-sm-12">QuickHelp</div>
  <div class="test-square-top col-xs-12 visible-xs-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">s1</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/stwbger0/2/)

You might want to checkout the new Bootstrap 4 Alpha release.
There is an option to turn on a [Flexbox Grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) which might make this possible without duplicating content (not 100% sure on that).